# How do I get iTunes to download and sync all podcasts

Tags: iphone, itunes

I subscribe to the Bloomberg on the Economy and Bloomberg Surveillance podcasts. Both of these podcasts tend to release multiple episodes at once, so my iTunes only gets the most recent episode when it starts up. Then when I connect my iPhone, I only get that most recent episode synced, when I'd really like to get all of the episodes. As such, I miss many of the episodes. The only way I can figure to solve the problem is to start iTunes each morning, then go into each podcast and select Get all to make sure I've got all the episodes, then reconnect my iPhone. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the settings button within the podcast section of iTunes, you can specify the behaviour when it detects new podcasts are available. It sounds like you have it set to the "Download the most recent one" option, when you want "Download all". Once they're downloaded, that should also solve the issue of syncing as well.

Comment: Boo on Apple for putting the settings button in the lower left hand part of the screen, meanwhile I'm looking at the top middle. There is no settings option in any of the context menu, nor the main menu. Thats bad UI design if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell iTunes to sync and keep any number of the most recent podcasts.

For example, I usually tell it to keep the most recent 2, because if i get more than 2 behind, it's too old for me.

There are many settings you can set with syncing that should do this for you. When you plug your iPhone in, click on it on the left hand menu, then go to Podcast sync options.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there WindyCityEagle,

I'm not sure if these settings are also available in iTunes for Windows. 
But this is how I tweaked the settings on a Mac:

**Download multiple items:**

1. Click on the podcasts folder in your library
2. Click on the "Settings..." button (next to Subscribe button bottom left)
3. Uncheck "Use default settings"
4. Choose the option "download all"

**Syncing all unplayed podcasts with your iPod/iPhone:**

5. Connect your iPod/iPhone
6. Click on the podcasts tab
7. make sure "Sync"is checked
8. select the option "all unheard"

Hope this works on your version of iTunes too (I'm using v9 on Snow Leopard).

Kind regards,

Jasper Rijkeboer

Comment: Jaspio - do you know how to change the podcast settings globally rather than for each individual podcast?  I recall seeing a Podcast tab in the Settings dialog of earlier versions of iTunes but I don't see it in v9.

Comment: Matt: the global settings are hidden in a context menu(s). --Downloading-- 1. Select the podcasts folder in your library 2. Click on the settings button in the grey bar at the bottom of the itunes window. --Syncing-- similarly: global podcast synching options are only available when your ipod is connected and you have enabled podcast synching.